# AttributeError: '_Helper' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python, encoding

i connect with the client to the server when i enter `help` i get AttributeError: '_Helper' object has no attribute 'encode'

this is the full output

```
-:-:-:-:-:Server:-:-:-:-:-
Connection from: ('127.0.0.1', 58675)
Your Instruction: help
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "serverback.py", line 36, in <module>
    msg = msg.encode("UTF-8")
AttributeError: '_Helper' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

this is my python script

```
#imports
import socket
import os
import sys
#Variables
port = int(sys.argv[1])

#Functions

def clear():
    os.system('cls' if os.name=='nt' else 'clear')

#Starting Server
serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = socket.gethostname()
serversocket.bind((host, port))
serversocket.listen(1)

clear()
print("-:-:-:-:-:Py Server:-:-:-:-:-")
clientsocket, addr = serversocket.accept()
print("Connection from: " + str(addr))
while True:
    msg = input("Your Instruction: ")

    if msg == "help":
        clear()
        print("-+-+-+-+-+HELP+-+-+-+-+-")
        print("Test Connection: 'test'")

        input("\nPress ENTER to continue")
        clear()
        print("-:-:-:-:-:Py Server:-:-:-:-:-")

    else:
        msg = msg.encode("UTF-8")
        clientsocket.send(msg)
        msg = clientsocket.recv(4096)
        print(msg.decode("UTF-8"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is **msg** undefined for some reason?  In Python3+ input should always return a string, but for some reason it appears your **msg** variable is not a string when the else condition is hit.   You could explicitly cast msg to a string.

```
else:
    msg = str(msg).encode("UTF-8")
    clientsocket.send(msg)
    msg = clientsocket.recv(4096)
    print(msg.decode("UTF-8"))
```